Change how sidebars are displayed on mobile only
My site is explorestj.com. It is set up to show as sidebar-content-sidebar on desktop. Mobile shows it at content-primary sidebar. The secondary sidebar does not show on mobile. Any idea how to fix this?
The theme is Customify. They have not responded to a question about this.
Thanks!
I cannot seem to get anything to change this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
